Liquibase Update on Git Push
I'm working on creating a web-page interface to manage a database. The project has a simple login portal with tools to add/modify users. The database contains the list of users, and will also contain the data that the web-page is meant to manage. I'm using liquibase to keep a history of changes to the database. All of this is set up to run in Docker.
When a user submits data on the web-page, I want that data to be added to a changelog file and then have something to trigger a liquibase update command.
This web-page is a project in itself, while the data that it is meant to work with is part of another project, ideally in its own separate git repository. I want to be able to just give some credentials to the docker service to allow it to access a git repository where the changelog files are stored. That way, if I were to fire up my docker-compose file on a random computer, it would pull the changelog files and then be up and running and full of data.
I've been trying to think of an elegant way to implement this, or something similar. One method I've been thinking about is to have the php service push the changelog files to a git repository which then triggers a webhook that causes the liquibase service to pull the new changes and run update. I was wondering if anyone has some thoughts on how I could get started trying to get that to work, or maybe some ideas to do it a different way.
This is all new to me. I'm just doing it for the sake of learning. Any advice is appreciated.
Here is the docker-compose.yml file:
# Filename: docker-compose.yml

version: '3.1'

services:
  frontend:
    image: nginx:1.25.4
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
      - ./app:/app
    depends_on:
      - backend

  backend:
    image: php:8.2-fpm
    hostname: php
    secrets:
      - db_root_password
      - db_admin_password
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
      - ./liquibase:/liquibase/changelog # Sharing the liquibase changelog with PHP container
    depends_on:
      - database
    command: ["sh", "-c", "docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && php /app/add_initial_user.php && docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm"]
    healthcheck:
    # Test is using the php command to check if the service is healthy by running /app/add_user.php
      test: ["CMD", "php", "/app/db_connect.php"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_NAME: app_db
      DB_USER: admin
      DB_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_admin_password
      DB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_root_password

  database:
    image: mysql:8.3.0
    hostname: db
    secrets:
      - db_admin_password
      - db_root_password
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: app_db
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_admin_password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_root_password
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
    # Test is using the mysqladmin command to check if the service is healthy
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10

  liquibase:
    image: liquibase/liquibase:4.27.0
    secrets:
      - db_root_password
    depends_on:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ./liquibase/changelog:/liquibase/changelog
      - ./liquibase/update.sh:/liquibase/update.sh
    environment:
      - INSTALL_MYSQL=true

    # The command to run the liquibase container
    command: ["sh", "-c", "/liquibase/update.sh"]

secrets:
  db_admin_password:
    external: true
  db_root_password:
    external: true

volumes:
  db_data: {}

Currently I have a volume shared by the php and liquibase services, and script in the liquibase service that periodically runs an update command. This works, but there's definitely room for improvement.
